# MongoDB working on local server.js but saying error on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

on deploying meanapp , mongodb is working fine on local node server.js but when i deploy to heroku it showing error

> 2019-06-04T02:49:12.401001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up
>   to starting
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:13.706279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes
>   with SIGTERM
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:13.800926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 143
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:17.993509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `node server.js`
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:20.786431+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-dlcak.mongodb.net
>
> /test?retryWrites=true 2019-06-04T02:49:20.803912+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app listening at 40970
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:20.972565+00:00 app[web.1]: database error
>   MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to
>   cluster0-shard-00-01-dlcak.mongodb.net:27017 closed
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:20.973723+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: callback is not a
>   function
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:20.973725+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   $initialConnection.$initialConnection.then
>   (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:638:13)
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:20.973810+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:20.973880+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>
> 2019-06-04T02:49:21.758205+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to up

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution while searching,

1. go to mongodb atlas
2. click `security` -> `Network Access` ->  `ADD IP ADDRESS` -> Choose allow access from anywhere and save
3. click `connect` and get your application to your code and paste to your application.

Answer (score 0):

How is it configured on Heroku?

**Use**
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab  -- for reference

**Add**

`const mongo_url = process.env.MONGO_URI || "YOUR_URL_HERE";`

to your code

Comment: you need to put MONGODB_URI variable mongoDB url (mongodb+srv://xyz:abc@cluster0-dlcak.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority) inside Config Vars which is located in heroku settings